# Highcharts not showing on HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, html, charts, highcharts

I've been creating some charts using Highcharts. I've also been able to show most of them on a web page except one. (And I have no idea why)

My php is the following :

**test.php**

```
<html>
   <head></head>
<body>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$ (function () {
        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {  


    var data_array = json;

    var series_array = [];
    //Starts with 1 and finishes with length - 1 to avoid first and last item
    for (var i = 1; i < data_array.length - 1; ++i) {
        series_array.push({
            name: data_array[i].name,
            data: data_array[i].data,
            type: 'column'
        });
    }

    series_array.push({
        name: data_array[data_array.length - 1].name,
        data: data_array[data_array.length - 1].data,
        type: 'line',
        yAxis: 1
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {            
            alignTicks: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'TCH Drop'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: data_array[0]["data"]
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0, 
            max: 100,
            title: {
                text: 'Percentage (%)'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        }, {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }],
            opposite: true
        }],
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + ' %<br/>';
            }

        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: series_array
    }); 

    });

}); 
</script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I go to my other php file where I show my html page and I put something like :

**page.php**

```
<?php 

$html=<<<HTML
...
...
...

<div id="container" class="6u  6u(xsmall)"> 
HTML;
include ('test.php');                               
$html.=<<<HTML
</div> 

...
...
HTML; 
echo $html; 
?>
```

I know that it's surely not the best way to do it, but I'm very new to this. 
With other charts, it worked fine. But with this one it doesn't show anything.

Does anybody has any idea why it is not working?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Here's my JSON :

```
[{"name":"Period_start_time","data":["2015-08-03","2015-08-01","2015-08-02","2015-08-03","2015-08-04","2015-08-05","2015-08-07","2015-08-08","2015-08-09","2015-08-10"]},{"name":"dcr_34","data":[35.42,40.78,31.68,35.42,35.81,37.21,38.41,39.9,33.93,40.93]},{"name":"dcr_35","data":[53.75,47.06,55.78,53.75,51.63,55.15,48.01,48.99,51.34,46.51]},{"name":"dcr_36","data":[0,0.39,0,0,0.47,0,0.66,0.51,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_37","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_38","data":[5,10.2,8.25,5,7.44,4.65,10.93,7.07,8.48,9.3]},{"name":"dcr_39","data":[0,0,0.33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_40","data":[1.67,0,0.99,1.67,1.86,1.33,0.66,0.51,0.89,0.93]},{"name":"dcr_41","data":[0.83,1.57,0.66,0.83,2.79,1.66,1.32,2.53,2.23,0.47]},{"name":"dcr_42","data":[0,0,2.31,0,0,0,0,0.51,3.13,0]},{"name":"dcr_43","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_44","data":[3.33,0,0,3.33,0,0,0,0,0,1.86]},{"name":"dcr_45","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_46","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_47","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_4g","data":[3.97,3.83,3.78,3.97,3.16,4.31,4.39,3.2,3.14,3.67]}]
```

Comment: please, paste your console errors, and try to move the highcarts script calls to above of the execution script

Comment: How your series_array looks like ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Thank you for your feedback. I added my data.php so you can see how it looks like.

Comment: I mean a json, how looks like, because we have no information about your database. So please paste your output json.

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Oh yes sorry. I've just edited it.

Comment: Well, I run your json and seems to be correct, see that: http://jsfiddle.net/eqnpLx6q/1/ Run a console (developer tools in browser) and observe if you receive any errors.

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Thanks for checking. And ok I'll do that. Did you include it (as I did above) as a js file or as a php file? Because my charts and my main html page aren't in the same file.

Comment: Well, I based my demo on your json, so only what you need is communicate your php with html/js by $.getJSON()

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Yea thank you again. I found out what was my problem, I wrote <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script><script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>  twice !

Comment: So now all works properly, I guess ;)

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Yes this part is working well, thanks ! I was wondering though if Highcharts can get JSON from a data.php that uses $search = $_GET [ 'search' ]; please?! Because Highcharts works fine when I use static values but not when I use  $_GET [ 'search' ] in my SQL request in my data.php file .. (even though my JSON returns the correct data)

Comment: You can try to use a $.getJSON(url+yourgetvalue) or $.post().

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Yes that's what I've just done and it's working! Thank you so much for your answers, they really helped!